# Most basic input devices: What can we use other than a keyboard to make selections in the BIOS and during installation?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, bios, input-devices

I wonder if there is anything else that might conceivably be used to input commands. I am sure there must be some imaginative possibilities!

Comment: This isn;t really Ubuntu-specific,and may be closed as off-topic.

Comment: UEFI BIOS can be pointer-device-controlled. Ubuntu installation can be done all-mouse anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done a small research based on your interesting question, assuming to find nothing, but I have met these:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyer
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chorded_keyboard

These are funny devices for entering text like playing a piano, you use one or more keys together to enter characters. The first one has been designed for so called *wearable computing*.

Don't know if you're seriously looking for a replacement for keyboard, but if you're just curious you may read this : http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=54675.54695 . It looks like some large document on input.

Also voice recognition is an option, but for bios, not this decade I guess :)